# PostSharp explorer there is no aspect in the current solution

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I am using PostSharp 6.2.8 for Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). My solution is .Net Core 2.2 Solution.

I created an aspect. But in PostSharp Explorer, I see this message:

[image: screenshot1]

I installed PostSharp NuGet Package (6.2.8) at every project which I am using aspect or referring.

I installed PostSharp 6.2.8 extension to Visual Studio. I build solution successfully.

Besides, Test that refer to aspects don't run and at debugging breakpoints are missed.

Aspect Code:

```
[Serializable]
public class FluentValidationAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    Type _validatorType;

    public FluentValidationAspect(Type validatorType)
    {
        _validatorType = validatorType;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType);
        var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var entities = args.Arguments.Where(t => t.GetType() == entityType);

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            ValidatorTool.FluentValidate(validator, entity);
        }
    }
}
....
public WordValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(w => w.WordText).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(w => w.WordText).Length(1, 250);
    }
```

Aspect Call:

```
public class WordManager : IWordService
{
    ...

    [FluentValidationAspect(typeof(WordValidator))]
    public Word Add(Word word)
    {
        //ValidatorTool.FluentValidate(new WordValidator(), word);
        return _wordDal.Add(word);
    }
...
}
```

Aspect Test:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]
    [TestMethod]
    public void Word_validation_check()
    {
        Mock<IWordDal> mock = new Mock<IWordDal>();
        WordManager wordManager = new WordManager(mock.Object);

        Word word = new Word() { WordText = "" };

        wordManager.Add(word);

    }
```

Comment: @emert117 Is a [YouProject.pssym] file present in the output directory? Is there a PDB file? Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @DanielBalas pssym files exist. I am using VS Enterprise 2019 (16.1.4)

Comment: @emert117 I was not able to reproduce the described behavior. If you are able to create a reproduction project, you can then file a bug and upload the reproduction [on our support site](https://www.postsharp.net/support). Thanks.

Comment: FYI we've did a lot of fixes and changes to PostSharp Explorer in PostSharp 6.3 .